# Mapbox services refuses to import

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I have the following in my app build gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:ui:1.4.0"
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-services:5.8.0'
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'}
```

and have successfully run things such as a map and placing markers down etc. However, when I go to import anything from services, such as `import com.mapbox.services.android.navigation.ui.v5.NavigationLauncher;` Android Studio cannot find anything. I've tried different versions in case the imports I needed were deprecated but to no avail. Any ideas? All the tutorials and example code in the documentation and third-party all use these imports and I don't really see a way around them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the module-level `build.gradle` file, add the following dependencies:

```
// in addition to the rest of your build.gradle contents
// you should include the following repository and dependencies

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.42.6'
}
```

Comment: Oh that dependency did it! Thank you so much, guess the documentation needs to be a bit clearer on exactly what dependency to use!